# Custom listview adapter for android - how to get proper view in getView()?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter

I'm trying to write a custom adapter to adapt a simple class into a ListView. The class is for SMS messages and it contains simple fields like body, sender address, etc. Below, see my adapter layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgContactPhoto"
    android:contentDescription="Contact photo"
    android:layout_width="90sp"
    android:layout_height="90sp" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblMsg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgContactPhoto" 
    android:paddingLeft="10sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my custom adapter class:

```
public class SmsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

  private int resource;
  private LayoutInflater inflater;
  private Context context;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public SmsListAdapter(Context ctx, int resourceId, List objects) {
      super(ctx, resourceId, objects);
      resource = resourceId;
      inflater = LayoutInflater.from( ctx );
      context=ctx;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //create a new view of the layout and inflate it in the row
        convertView = ( RelativeLayout ) inflater.inflate( resource, null );

        // Extract the object to show 
        Sms msg = (Sms) getItem(position);

        // Take the TextView from layout and set the message
        TextView lblMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblMsg);
        lblMsg.setText(msg.getBody());

        //Take the ImageView from layout and set the contact image
        long contactId = fetchContactId(msg.getSenderNum());
        String uriContactImg = getPhotoUri(contactId).toString();
        ImageView imgContactPhoto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgContactPhoto);
        int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uriContactImg, null, context.getPackageName());
        Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
        imgContactPhoto.setImageDrawable(image);
        return convertView;
  }
}
```

When I attempt to activate the adapter, I get an error on the first line of getView() saying that a TextView cannot be cast to a RelativeLayout.

What I'm not clear on is why that is a TextView in the first place. My list item layout is set as a RelativeLayout and that's what should be being inflated, unless I'm mistaken. Can anyone help me debug this?

Comment: how do you initialize your SmsListAdapter?

Comment: Specifically, what is the resourceId sent to it?

Comment: `ListView conversationListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstConvoThread);` `conversationListView.setAdapter(new SmsListAdapter(this, R.layout.smslistview_item_row, messages));` messages is an ArrayList<Sms>.

Comment: To be clear, `smslistview_item_row.xml` is the layout that you posted?

Comment: That doesn't make sense... Try cleaning your project. (I don't know why you are trying to convert it to a RelativeLayout since `convertView` is just a View, but that's not the problem.)

Comment: @Sam what do you mean by "cleaning" the project?

Comment: In Eclipse, go to `Project > Clean...` (On a rare occasion, Eclipse gets confused.)

Comment: If this doesn't help, try removing explicit cast to RelativeLayout, it is redundant in this case.

Comment: That fixed it - thanks guys. I'm not a hundred percent sure why, though. What do you mean when you say it's redundant?

Comment: I mean that there's no need for this cast. `findViewById()` works perfectly just on simple `View`, it doesn't need to be a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: You should watch this [Google Talk](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) to learn about View recycling, ViewHolders and other tips to write an efficient Adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the explicit cast of `convertView` to `RelativeLayout` should help.

Comment: Wrong, in fact I'd argue that it should be there for type safety if we know that we _always_ want this view to be a RelativeLayout. Also view recycling as shown in Gabe Sechan's answer below.

Comment: @zyklonSport First, findViewById() works perfectly just with simple View, it doesn't need to be a RelativeLayout, so type safety is not violated here. Second, it helped. Third, view recycling is indeed useful, but it has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 3):

On this line:

```
       convertView = ( RelativeLayout ) inflater.inflate( resource, null );
```

instead of resource, try using the full id of the layout-  R.layout.whatever

Also, you should only inflate the layout if the incoming view is null.  Otherwise the view is already inflated and you should just overwrite all its values.

Comment: eventually, `resource` value is equal to `R.layout.whatever`

Comment: I put the full id in but i'm getting the same result. Fairly certain it's being passed in correctly.

Comment: Sounds from the other comment thread that there was an eclipse screwup and cleaning the project worked.  But you do need this null check, otherwise you're losing a lot of the efficiency a listview gives you.  Without the null check you create a new row each time its called, with it you only create a new row on the first initialization and reassign them thereafter (inflating can be expensive).

Answer (score 2):

Use a BaseAdapter to create your custom adapter. This is a bit harder to manage from the start, but makes your work easier later on.

```
public class GeneralAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private LayoutInflater mInflater    = null;
private ArrayList<String> info      = null;

public GeneralAdapter( ArrayList<String> info ) {
    this.info = info;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return info.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return info.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.YOURLAYOUT, null);

        holder                  = new ViewHolder();
        holder.generalTV        = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblMsg);
        holder.generalIV        = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgContactPhoto);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.generalTV.setText(info.getBody());
    holder.generalIV.setBackgroundResource(R.id.YOURIMAGE);

    return null;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView generalTV;
    ImageView generalIV;
}

}
```